# nginx equivalent of Apache's `<IfFile…>`

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

Apache (as of v2.4.34) has an [`<IfFile path>` configuration directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#iffile). Does nginx have equivalent functionality? How can I do this?

In Apache, when the configuration is loaded, if that file exists, then it the apache directives inside the `<IfFile>…</IfFile>` is loaded. If not, everything inside is ignored.

This functionality is useful for (e.g.) enabling a HTTPS vhost only if the SSL cert is available, e.g.: (otherwise the apache config would be invalid without the filename).

```
<IfFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ... HTTPS site config
</VirtualHost>
</IfFile>
```